# Django2.0 “remove hardcoded urls in templates” not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm checking out django for the first time following the tutorial 
[[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/)

---

When I change the hardcoded url from:

```
<li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
```

to:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'detail' poll.id %}">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
```

I get a error as follow:

---

My urls.py files are:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex:/polls/5/
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='datail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    # ex: /polls/vote/
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
]
```

My views.py files are:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Question,Choice

def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question':question})

def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question':question})

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html',{
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes +=1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpRespinsedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list':latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

My index.html fils are:

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'detail' question_id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

my details.html fils are:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

So, I am confused of  **Removing hardcoded URLs in templates** does not work.
Could someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You didn't post the error. Nevertheless, it is because you have a typo in your urls.py: `datail` instead of `detail`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're great. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using name spacing in your urls. That is why you set the app_name to polls. Your url should look like this,

```
<li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
```

Right now your url conf doesn't know what detail your talking about.

Here is the url conf docs and name spacing is talked about at the bottom.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/

Comment: it's doesn't work also after I added.  I don't know why.

Comment: What does the error say? You should always post the error

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /polls/  .

Comment: Are your views located at polls/views?